# Division of Vectors by Scalars

Tags: notation, vectors, physics

I have a question about vector notation. In physics class today, my professor introduced the concept of average velocity. He defined it mathematically as

$$\vec{v} := \frac{\Delta \vec{x}}{\Delta \textrm{t}},$$

where $\Delta \vec{x}$ indicates the change in displacement over a time interval $\Delta \textrm{t}$.

However, in my previous math classes, I was always told that the division of a vector by a scalar was not a defined operation. For example, if I wanted to divide a vector $\vec{a}$ by a certain scalar $b$, I would write it as $\frac{1}{b}*\vec{a}$, not $\frac{\vec{a}}{b}$. Applying this to average velocity would entail that its definition should be 
$$\vec{v} := \frac{1}{\Delta \textrm{t}}*\Delta \vec{x}.$$

Is this a valid statement? Or am I misunderstanding the vector/scalar division comment from my previous classes?

Comment: Unless you want to be really formal about it, you can divide by a scalar, no problem, which is equivalent to multiplying with the inverse.

Comment: Why is it not correct formally to have the division with quotients, rather than multiplying by the inverse?

Comment: is what I guess I was trying to get at in the first place

Comment: To be honest, I don't really know, but I suspect it is so that mathematicians can get away with defining one less operation ;P Someone else will have to fill in!

Comment: Damn, 4 years and still nothing. Whoever comes up with an answer will probably get a Nobel prize.